# Specialized overload/implementation of a generic function with a default parameter value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic function with a required `transformer` generic function parameter and a generic return type `T`.

I want to add a "default value" for that `transformer` parameter that has a concrete type (`ArrayBuffer`).

I think I've written the overload signatures correct, but my implementation does not compile.

```js
export async function downloadWithCache(
  url: string
): Promise<ArrayBuffer>;
export async function downloadWithCache<T>(
  url: string,
  transformer: (buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T
): Promise<T>;
export async function downloadWithCache<T>(
  url: string,
  transformer?: (buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T
) {
  return someImplementation(url, transformer || (x => x));
}
```

```
Argument of type '((buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T) | ((x: ArrayBuffer) => ArrayBuffer)' is not assignable to parameter of type '(buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T'.
  Type '(x: ArrayBuffer) => ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type '(buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T'.
    Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'ArrayBuffer'.ts(2345)
```

P.S. I think that `someImplementation` is irrelevant, but I was asked to post it:

```
const httpGetDataWithCache = async <T>(
  url: string,
  transformer: (buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T,
  cacheName: string = "cache",
  updateIfInCache: boolean = false
): Promise<T> => {
  const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
  let response = await cache.match(url);
  let needToUpdateCache = false;
  if (response === undefined || updateIfInCache) {
    try {
      const newResponse = await fetch(url);
      if (!newResponse.ok) {
        throw new Error(
          `Network response was not OK: ${newResponse.status}: ${newResponse.statusText}`
        );
      }
      response = newResponse;
      needToUpdateCache = true;
    } catch (err) {
      if (response === undefined) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }
  // Preventing TypeError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'Cache': Response body is already used
  const responseForCaching = response.clone();
  // Need to verify that the transformer executes with error before putting data in cache.
  const result = transformer(await response.arrayBuffer());
  if (needToUpdateCache) {
    await cache.put(url, responseForCaching);
  }
  return result;
};

const someImplementation = httpGetDataWithCache;
```

Comment: please share `someImplementation`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine I really think it's irrelevant... But I've now added it.

Comment: @Ark-kun the implementation of someImplementation is irrelevant, but the type signature of someImplementation is relevant

Comment: You need to loose strictness a bit inside your function body. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/wjnevw) . It is safe, because inner body of function treats callback as `(buffer: ArrayBuffer) => ArrayBuffer` whereas outter function representation treats it as `(buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T`

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. It seems really weird that the overload with `transformer: (buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T` does not conflict with the implementation signature `transformer: (buffer: ArrayBuffer) => ArrayBuffer` despite `T` not being a descendant of `ArrayBuffer`. I thought that the implementation signature must be compatible with all overload signatures type-wise. Thank you.

Comment: Overloads are bivariant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change function type signature:

```js
declare const someImplementation: <T>(
    url: string,
    transformer: (buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T,
    cacheName?: string,
    updateIfInCache?: boolean
) => Promise<T>

export async function downloadWithCache(
    url: string
): Promise<ArrayBuffer>;
export async function downloadWithCache<T>(
    url: string,
    transformer: (buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T
): Promise<T>;

export async function downloadWithCache(
    url: string,
    transformer?: (buffer: ArrayBuffer) => ArrayBuffer // CHANGE IS HERE
) {
    return someImplementation(url, transformer || (x => x));
}

downloadWithCache('a', (x) => x.byteLength) // ok, Promise<number>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRGPXN)

It works because function overloads are [bivariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc).

See simplified example:

```js
declare let a: (buffer: ArrayBuffer) => ArrayBuffer
declare let b: <T, >(buffer: ArrayBuffer) => T

a = b // ok
b = a // error
```

At least one operation should be ok to make overloadings work.

See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

> The implementation signature must also be compatible with the overload signatures.

In our case, implementation is compatible with overload signature, but not vice versa